# ADB Router does not detect new ethernet devices

Tags: router, wireless-router, lan, broadband

My router doesn't let any devices to be connected via ethernet but wifi is accepted and devices who were still connected on ethernet do work but new incoming devices to ethernet just no it wont accept it. And maybe TV setup boxes will be having the same issue so maybe the factory reset is the choice but i want to keep the firewall on. I think i will just wait a bit for a magic to happen

Comment: So what is your question? Could you provide more details so we can help you, the "question" you have provided above may be flagged as very low quality.

Comment: i might wait for a day and maybe it will just magicly fix it self. But its in almost R.I.P state

Comment: Also my TV Setup boxes are plugged in the router and thats the worst thing im scared of. it might not let any devices to be plugged. Beacuse my router found a device but didnt want to give network access. theres also no frimware updates so that router cant be updated

Comment: @Cat its a question let me just explain a bit further. My router doesnt let any devices to be connected via ethernet but wifi is accepted and devices who were still connected on ethernet do work but new incoming devices to ethernet just no it wont accept it

Comment: Reset the router.

Comment: @DavidPostill good idea but sometimes people have to work overnight so i cant use the router but after a day i can reset it and then i cant its just her work schedule so i might try my best see if it wont disconnect and ignore devices that were plugged in. It could be a glitch. and also my router is protected from ddos attacks because someone spoofed my ip and i firewall was enabled by default because my isp wanted devices to be safe which was why this router was worth a money

Comment: after waiting it didnt help so i think the real choice was the restart but i have to wait a day before they arent using the router